# Is there some plugin that can capture JavaScript requests in browser?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Just a plugin that can only capture JavaScript requests.

Answer (score 1):

[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/) can grab all http requests made by the browser including ones from Flash.

Comment: What about those non-http requests?